# How to fetch all active and inactive tasks in snowflake

Tags: sql, stream, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, task

I need to fetch all active and inactive tasks in snowflake

I tried using task_history function..

Answer (score 0):

I would use the task_versions view in account_usage:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/account-usage/task_versions.html

This view is currently Public Preview, but should have what you are looking for.